# Incorrect results with sqlite julianday adding seconds

Tags: sqlite

When testing some queries with sqlite (v3.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04) I have noticed some strange behavior.  The results with julianday math are not always consistent.

For example,

```
sqlite> select julianday('now')-julianday('now','+9 seconds');
```

Returns correctly: -0.0001041670329 (*24*60*60 = −9.000031643)

However,

```
sqlite> select julianday('now')-julianday('now','+8 seconds');
```

Returns:  -9.2592556029558 (???)

Around '+8.64 seconds' (0.0001 days) the results are inconsistent, sometimes the correct value appears, other times not.  This appears to be true when using '+0.0001 days' as well.

This is a problem for me as I am counting on being able to add small values (<1 second) to some date and compare with 'now' in my application.

Am I using julianday incorrectly here?

Thanks!

Comment: won't 'now' change between the two parts of the query? Might by how much be a little unpredicatable?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's certainly possible.  However, the difference in my first example shows approximately the correct value (~9 seconds), and the second shows ~9.25 days - very different.

Comment: oh, I got misled because I saw the two numbers in your problem −9.000031643 and : -9.2592556029558 looked pretty close. But one was your conversion of the result and one was not. It does make me wonder, though, if maybe SQLITE is returning things in different units for some unknown reason.

Comment: I just ran this at https://sqliteonline.com/ and your second query gave -0.00009259255602955818. Are you sure you didn't just get some scientific notation at the end like E -5 that got cut off or ignored?

Comment: Wow.  Yes.  You're exactly right.  I'm using sqlite from the terminal and my column width was not set correctly - now I can see -9.25925560295582e-05.  Thanks for your help!  And thanks for mentioning sqliteonline.com, that's a really useful resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of julianday was correct. This turned out to be an issue of column width was not set correctly - so the e-05 in the result -9.25925560295582e-05 was unseen. That turned out to be -0.0000925925560295582 after all, which was the right size.